# My code is moving to where it shouldnt be

Tags: html, vb.net, function, visual-studio-code, tr

I was writing a code to build a personal website, everything seems fine in my vscode but on the web when i check it, a particular parameter is appearing where it shouldn't be appearing . Like the content for work experience is appearing under skills in between the content for skills and the sub heading itself

After writing the code and rewriting I expected the contents for a sub topic to appear under it not under another sub topic

Comment: Hey. Unfortunately your question is not really explaining the issue. Can you provide more details on your issue. What are you trying to achieve, how does it look like right now. What have you tried. What language/framework are you using. These details might help others to support you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.